# Giving a table CSS class

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to make a table with custom CSS, and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.  Done this before, but for some reason am unable to get the darn CSS to show up... Just shows a blank table with no style.

CSS:

```
table.300yardsTable{background:#EEE;color:#333;font-size:14px;text-align:center;}
table.300yardsTableHeader tr{background:#CCC;font-weight:bold;}
table.300yardsRow tr{background:#EEE;color:#333;}
table.300yardsRow:hover tr{background:#242424;color:#CCC;}
```

Table:

```
<table width="600" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" class="300yardsTable">
<tr class="300yardsTableHeader">
    <td width="25%">LOFT</td>
    <td width="25%">HAND</td>
    <td width="25%">LIE</td>
    <td width="25%">VOLUME</td>
</tr>
<tr class="300yardsRow">
    <td>8*-12*</td>
    <td>RH/LH</td>
    <td>61*</td>
    <td>460cc</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your css is wrong the classes are on the tr's not the table.

```
tr.yardsTableHeader tr{background:#CCC;font-weight:bold;}
tr.yardsRow {background:#EEE;color:#333;}
tr.yardsRow:hover{background:#242424;color:#CCC;}
```

Remove #'s from class names

Comment: He also needs to change the name.  can't start with a #.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot start a css classname with a number. So 300yearsTableHeader is an invalid name

[The spec gives more on this.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters)

Answer (score 3):

I believe you cannot use a number to start a CSS property. Try using `.yardsTable` instead of `.300yardsTable`.

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to start `class` name with an `integer`. [Check out the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mnTD3/1/).

Answer (score 0):

```
.300yardsTable {background:#EEE;color:#333;font-size:14px;text-align:center;}

    .300yardsTable .300yardsTableHeader {background:#CCC;font-weight:bold;}

    .300yardsTable .300yardsRow {background:#EEE;color:#333;}
         .300yardsTable .300yardsRow:hover {background:#242424;color:#CCC;}
```

Css selector name  cannot start with a digit.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, you can't start the class name with a #.  Also, need to either drop the 'table' prefix or change those that are on the tr's with tr.classname